# powershell: Set-ADUser : The requested operation did not satisfy one or more constraints associated with the class of the object

Tags: powershell

To test another Script, I created a quick and dirty Powershellscript to be able to create and delete a lot of Useraccounts in multiple OUs in 2 different domains.

While the creation works without problems, I can't manage to fill the accounts via Set-AdUser with some attributes, when setting up `$num` with a value above 1000. However: the Script works fine if I start at 1 or 100.

I always reveice the following error when using 1000+:

```
Set-ADUser : The requested operation did not satisfy one or more constraints associated with the class of the object
At C:\Users\Administrator.TEST\Desktop\ps\createSomeUsers.ps1:117 char:9
+         Set-ADUser -Identity $num -replace $hash -Server $dc2 -Credential $W ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (10000000:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8212,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

---

Where does this come from? Is that a problem in my Script? If I use the set-AdUser manually with a value of 10000000 it seems to work without a problem.

For testing purposes it is essential that I use a number with 8 digits!

Here's the whole thing:

```
$dc1 = "192.168.3.99" # DC1
$dc2 = "192.168.2.99"  # DC2

# OUs in where to create the accounts
$ou1_1 = "OU=Users,OU=mop,OU=e01,OU=DE,OU=EMEA,DC=relf,DC=com"
$ou2_1 = "OU=Users,OU=loh,OU=e03,OU=DE,OU=EMEA,DC=relf,DC=com"
$ou3_1 = "OU=Users,OU=fer,OU=e05,OU=DE,OU=EMEA,DC=relf,DC=com"

$ou1_2 = "OU=Users,OU=mop,OU=e01,OU=DE,OU=EMEA,DC=TEST,DC=com"
$ou2_2 = "OU=Users,OU=loh,OU=e03,OU=DE,OU=EMEA,DC=TEST,DC=com"
$ou3_2 = "OU=Users,OU=fer,OU=e05,OU=DE,OU=EMEA,DC=TEST,DC=com"

# number of users in OUs
$ou1_amount = 1
$ou2_amount = 1
$ou3_amount = 1

# numeration
$num = 10000000

# total Nr. of accounts
$acc_total = $ou1_amount + $ou2_amount + $ou3_amount

# path and filename 4 .logfiles
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$curdir = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
# check if logfile folder is not created yet, if not: create
$tp = $curdir + "\logfiles\"
if (!(Test-Path -Path $tp)) {
new-item $tp -itemtype directory
}
$logfilepath = $tp

# Username and PW for dc1 and dc2:
$creds1 = "relf\PS-User"
$creds2 = "TEST\PS-User"
$pass1 = gc $curdir"\securestring1.txt" | convertto-securestring 
$pass2 = gc $curdir"\securestring2.txt" | convertto-securestring 
$WPS_AdminCredentials1 = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $creds1,$pass1    
$WPS_AdminCredentials2 = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $creds2,$pass2   

# Attributes
$attributes = "c","co","company","countryCode","department","Description","displayName",
                "givenName","mail","physicalDeliveryOfficeName","postalAddress",
                "postalCode","sAMAccountName","sn","st","streetAddress",
                "telephoneNumber","title","wWWHomePage","l","postOfficeBox"

# The ultimate question
$d_O_c = Read-Host '[D]elete OR [C]reate?'

if ($d_O_c -eq "c") {
    write-host "OU1"
    while ($ou1_amount -gt 0) {
        New-ADUser -Name $num -Path $ou1_1 -SamAccountName $num -DisplayName $num -Server $dc1 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials1 `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "pw1234" -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true

        New-ADUser -Name $num -Path $ou1_2 -SamAccountName $num -DisplayName $num -Server $dc2 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials2 `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "pw1234" -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true

        write-host $num "of" $acc_total "created"
        $ou1_amount--
        $num++
        }

    write-host "OU2"
    while ($ou2_amount -gt 0) {
        New-ADUser -Name $num -Path $ou2_1 -SamAccountName $num -DisplayName $num -Server $dc1 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials1 `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "pw1234" -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true

        New-ADUser -Name $num -Path $ou2_2 -SamAccountName $num -DisplayName $num -Server $dc2 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials2 `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "pw1234" -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true

        write-host $num "of" $acc_total "created"
        $ou2_amount--
        $num++
        }

    write-host "OU3"
    while ($ou3_amount -gt 0) {
        New-ADUser -Name $num -Path $ou3_1 -SamAccountName $num -DisplayName $num -Server $dc1 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials1 `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "pw1234" -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true

        New-ADUser -Name $num -Path $ou3_2 -SamAccountName $num -DisplayName $num -Server $dc2 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials2 `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "pw1234" -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true

        write-host $num "of" $acc_total "created"
        $ou3_amount--
        $num++
        }
`
    $num--
    while ($num -ge 10000000) {
        $hash = @{}
        $attributes | % {
            $hash[$_] = $num
        }
        Set-ADUser -Identity $num -replace $hash -Server $dc2 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials2
        write-host $num "edited"
        $num--
    }
}
elseif ($d_O_c -eq "d") {
    $latest = 10000000 + $acc_total
    $latest--
    while ($latest -ge 10000000) {
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $latest -Confirm:$false -Server $dc1 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials1
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $latest -Confirm:$false -Server $dc2 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials2
    write-host $latest "deleted"
    $latest--
    }
}
```

EDIT: As mentioned by Matt in the comments, the error message is simply related to some restrictions that are on some of the attributes in the AD.
Im now using another, shorter value for all attributes.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a number for the Identity? It calls for an object of the `ADUser` type. It seems to make more sense to me to filter a `Get-ADUser` query and pipe it to a `Foreach-Object Set-ADUser -Identity $_`... type statement. See here for details on the parameters: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx

Comment: Am I missing something? First the code you have shown does not have 117 lines in it where  the error is shown. Also what is the point of setting all attributes to the number `10000000` which is what the loop `$attributes | % { $hash[$_] = $num }` does? Setting all those properties to a numerical value is going to be an issue. Some of those most likely dont allow number or numbers that long.... have to look up the schema to be sure. That would be my guess as to the source of your error

Comment: yes thank you. it was indeed the high number that caused the error in some of the attributes as they seem to be limited to X letters/numbers.

As for the missing lines: I always have a larger 'header' with a lot of comments which I usually exclude. I should have mentioned that. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find the official documentation that I would like to add to this but it would seem that you are trying to assign an invalid value to AD object property based on the error you are getting:

> The requested operation did not satisfy one or more constraints associated with the class of the object

Looking at your sample it would seem that it comes from this section of code.

```
while ($num -ge 10000000) {
    $hash = @{}
    $attributes | % {
        $hash[$_] = $num
    }
    Set-ADUser -Identity $num -replace $hash -Server $dc2 -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials2
    write-host $num "edited"
    $num--
}
```

You are building `$hash` with AD properties and assigning them all value of `10000000` from what I can see. I know there are some properties that would not allow that. Not sure if you are making test/dummy account but you cannot simply create a bunch of users where *all* the settable properties are the same number.

**Side Note**

We talked in the comments about line numbers in errors and matching up to your code. In this case it was easy to find where the error came from but next time try and as clear as you can about what error and where the error occurred.

If you are still having issues with this please update your question or make a new question if it is too different than this one.